# Intersection of triangle and polygon

Tags: polygon, intersection

I have a triangle and an arbitrary polygon lying on the same plane in 3D space. I need to find the fastest way to determine if these two intersect, one is inside the other, or completely separated. At first stage, it's not important to find the intersection points or tell the difference between the states when one is inside the other and when they intersect.

The important thing is having the minimum number of calculations. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: What software are you using? I think you could do an intersection, then compare the area of the intersection with the original input.

Comment: I'm programming in c. Later on I might implement the algorithm with CUDA.

Comment: Can you provide us with the code you're using to store the geometries? Is it an array, or an external library, or what?

Answer (score 0):

I would select some speedy open source library which can do "Intersects" and is written in your favourite language and have a look at the source code. You say "on the same plane in 3D space" so I interpret that 2D Intersects tools will work for you. This benchmark could be of some value for you even it measures the speed of another operation http://rogue-modron.blogspot.fi/2011/04/polygon-clipping-wrapper-benchmark.html.